# COM+: managed code in server and client part needs DCOM protocol?

Tags: .net, remoting, com+, dcom

We developed many solutions in COM+ 1.0 environment: Old VB6 DLL hosted in COM+ 1.0 and exposed to VB6 clients, where the protocol for distributed work was DCOM. We developed managed code COM hosted in COM+ 1.0 too with legacy VB6 clients, and all worked.

But now we have to implement communication of managed code both into the client and server parts.

We would like to use COM+ 1.5 with managed code in hosted COM and .NET client, and the only thing we are asking ourselves is if COM+ will again use DCOM as transport application protocol.

To be more clearer: managed code in server and client part needs DCOM protocol?

Comment: Why would you do this when WCF is available?

Comment: We need transactions and Pooling. Further we already have skills on COM+ instead of WCF.